# how i can covert 01 Jun, 2019 03:53 PM into "d m y h:m"?

Tags: php

How I can convert `01 Jun, 2019 03:53 PM` this to store in the database. I have tried `strtotime` function but not convert it. Still getting an empty result after trying `strtotime`.

Comment: `DateTime::createFromFormat` magic is the key

Comment: tried but still getting the same empty result,

Comment: $mdf4_arrival_datetime = '01 Jun, 2019 03:53 PM';
    $date = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y:H:i:s', $mdf4_arrival_datetime);
    print_r($date);

Comment: The first parameter of date_create_from_format() is your input fomart, so it knows how to read your date. It is not an output format.
You have a few examples here : https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [**date_create_from_format()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-create-from-format.php). `date_create_from_format()` returns a new DateTime object formatted according to the specified format.

```
$obj = date_create_from_format('j M, Y h:i A', '01 Jun, 2019 03:53 PM');
echo $obj->format('d m Y h:i');
```